# How does Wipeout Omega Collection work?

Tags: wipeout-omega-collection

I'm thinking of buying a PS4, mainly just for this one game! Wipeout has always been one of my favourite games

After checking out some reviews online, I am slightly put off to see that the different games in the collection are kinda 'separated'.

E.g. you have to choose which mode you want to play, such as either '2048' or 'HD / Fury'

Does this mean that, if you want to play Wipeout 2048 then you can only choose the ships that originally came on the 2048 game? And you can't, for example, play any of the HD / Fury tracks in a Wipeout 2048 ship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's right, 2048 is completely separated from HD/Fury in WipEout Omega Collection. So you can neither run on a 2048 track with a HD/Fury ship (like Triakis, Assegai, EG-X...) nor run on a HD/Fury track with a 2048 ship (like the "Prototypes" models).

Comment: wow, that is a real shame! thanks for letting me know anyway

Comment: Yes that's kinda frustrating, but WipEout Omega Collection is still a very good game. :) You're welcome!

Comment: I am tempted to get it anyway, is there much of an online community these days? also I love the F1 style sound effects! are these on each game or just 2048?